# closest() not working for table

Tags: jquery, html-table, cakephp-1.3, closest

I have a html page where I am implementing a "add more" feature. When a user clicks `add more` link, a new `<tr>` is created within the table. See tha code below :

```
<?php 
$city_more_attributes = array("empty" => "--- Select City ---","id" =>"morecitylist", "class" => "more_locations_list","onchange" => "load_sublocations(this.value)");
?>


var counter = 0;

$('#add_more_city').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    //var city = '<?php echo json_encode($city_more); ?>';
    var city = '<?php  echo json_encode($form->select("GalStore.gal_location_id_'+counter+'", $gal_locations,null,$city_more_attributes)); ?>';
    var more_cities_elements = '';
    more_cities_elements += '<tr id="morecities_show_'+counter+'" class="morecities">';             
    more_cities_elements += '<td>Add City</td>';
    more_cities_elements += '<td id="more_'+counter+'"></td>';
    more_cities_elements += '<td><a href="#" id="more_close_'+counter+'" onclick="close_box('+counter+')">X</a></td>';
    more_cities_elements += '</tr>';
    //alert(more_cities_elements);

    if(counter == 1){
        $('#addmoreanchor').after(more_cities_elements);
    }else if(counter > 1){
        var mcshwid = counter - 1;
        $('#morecities_show_'+mcshwid).after(more_cities_elements);
    }
    $('#more_'+counter).html(city);

    var noofcities = $('.morecities').size();
    $('#counter').val(noofcities);

});
```

The above code produces a `<tr>` with an unique `id`. Within the `<tr>`, the line `more_'+counter).html(city);` produces and `<select> list` where `onchange = "load_sublocations(this.value)"` event is added . Within this function , I wrote :

```
function load_sublocations(gal_location_id) {
var trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
alert(trid);
}
```

But unfortunately it alerts `undefined` ! Whats the reason ? Why it is not showing the `tr` `id` ?

Comment: Just change `load_sublocations(this.value)` to `load_sublocations(this)` and `$(this).closest('tr').attr('id')` to `$(gal_location_id).closest('tr').attr('id')`. Your code would work fine!!

Comment: @palash yes Palas..I changed and working nicely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you are using inline event handler, `this` inside the handler does not refer to the clicked element, it refers the window element so pass the clicked element as an parameter to the handler method as shown below

```
load_sublocations(this)
```

then

```
function load_sublocations(el) {
var gal_location_id = this.value;
var trid = $(el).closest('tr').attr('id');
alert(trid);
}
```